# File installation properties

Tags: c#, installation, project

Hi I have a setup project in my application.Setup includes 5 files (a.txt,b.doc etc.)
and how can i do this:
**If this files exist in target computer,setup dont change them**
I am using visual studio 2008 and C#

Thx for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that a property "Condition" of setup file is what you want.
Also you can create your own CustomAction for setup project if there is no simple solutions

Comment: Ok Thx I found solution.But it's not customaction :).It's "Launch Conditions"